# ReportGenerator missing Code Coverage tab (Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1)

Tags: azure-devops

I follow the steps of [Computing code coverage for a .NET Core project with Azure DevOps and Coverlet](https://www.meziantou.net/computing-code-coverage-for-a-dotnet-core-project-with-azure-devops-and-coverlet.htm).

Build run like expected and every step ends successfully.

[image: Build results]

The Artefact-Explorer shown the uploaded report and In summary I get the Code Coverage result.

[image: CodeCoverage result]

But I missing the **Code Coverage** tab next to **Tests** tab to take a look to the detailed report.

**Configuration YAML:**

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.0.2'

  inputs:

    versionSpec: 5.0.2
    checkLatest: true


- task: NuGetCommand@2

  displayName: 'NuGet restore'

  inputs:

    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'


- task: VSBuild@1

  displayName: 'Projektmappe **\*.sln erstellen'

  inputs:

    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'  
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'


- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1

  displayName: 'Installer für Visual Studio Test-Plattform'
  enabled: false



- task: VSTest@2

  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'

  inputs:

    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**

    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'



- powershell: ./'D:\AzureDevOpsData\Skripte\PowerShell\CodeCoverage.ps1'

  displayName: 'PowerShell Test Code Coverage'



- task: Palmmedia.reportgenerator.reportgenerator-build-release-task.reportgenerator@4

  displayName: ReportGenerator

  inputs:

    reports: coverage.cobertura.xml
    targetdir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage'



- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1

  displayName: 'Code Coverage veröffentlichen von $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage/Cobertura.xml'

  inputs:

    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage/Cobertura.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage'
```

**The PowerShell Script contains:**

```
#TEST CSPROJ
$csproj = "FrameworkA_Tests"

#SEARCH TEST CSPROJ.DLL
"`nrun tests:"
$unitTestFile = gci -Recurse | ?{ $_.FullName -like "*bin\*$csproj.dll" }
Write-Host "`$unitTestFile value: $unitTestFile"

#GET COVERLET.EXE
$coverlet = "D:\AzureDevOpsData\Tools\coverlet\coverlet.exe"

#RUN COVERLET.EXE
"calling $coverlet for $($unitTestFile.FullName)"
&$coverlet $unitTestFile.FullName --target "dotnet" --targetargs "vstest $($unitTestFile.FullName) --logger:trx" --format "cobertura"
```

Do I forget something?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enable "Boards" in the project settings:

[image: Project settings]

This issue was fixed for *Azure DevOps* but may still exist in *Azure DevOps Server*.

See:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/385331/code-coverage-results-not-rendered-in-build-result.html
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/398209/build-results-tab-code-coverage-does-not-show-up.html

Comment: thanks for your response. Unfortunately I already had **Boards** activated. For test reasons I deactivate/reactivate it, but it doesn't change.

Comment: Next try: Open the console in your browser (F12) and reload the page in Azure Devops Server. Does any error occur in the console?

Comment: 2019.1 RC1 was released today with GoLive license. It may solve this for you.

Comment: @Daniel I checked the console of IE (the only browser where devops runs well) and there are an error and few warnings. The error is `SCRIPT12008: SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 403, Forbidden` and warning for example is `Timeline Shared Component: snapshotKey is not given for one of the child, that element won't render.` or `Cannot render contributed pivot ms.vss-build-web.build-results-summary-tab.`

Comment: @jessehouwing I will try a new installation of 2019.1 RC1, thanks for your advice.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue in 2019.1 RC1

Comment: You could try to execute the same build on *Azure DevOps*. If it works there, then it's probably a bug in *Azure DevOps Server* and you might want to open a new issue at Microsoft's bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

> ReportGenerator missing Code Coverage tab (Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1)

This should be a known issue on the Developer Community:

[Code coverage tab missing in Azure DevOps Server](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/578111/code-coverage-tab-missing-in-azure-devops-server.html)

MS team reply: **A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release.**

As workaround, you can try the method provided by jingzhu yan:

> you can add copy files and publish build results steps , then you can
>   download coverage result file from Artifacts.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Leo, thanks for your response. The result of your approch is shown in my first screenshot. The upload to the artifacts explorer is not the problem. The problem is that it is uncomfortable to download the .html and open it in your browser, if there is an alternative to open it directly in a separate CodeCoverage tab (as it should works normally). Another workaround I found is to upload the reports with `##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path` by [Logging Commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

Comment: @MarTin, Yes, upload the reports is also an effective workaround.