# Can't see Code Coverage from my code with Azure DevOps Build

Tags: c#, azure-devops, sonarqube

I'm not able to see Code Coverage from my code with Azure DevOps Build.

I was following SonarQube tutorial but I can't see anything about coverage on the SonarQube dashboard and anything from coverage on the summary build from Azure DevOps.

[image: This is the result from the build]

The build get success but I still haven't coverage.

What should I do?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT we know now that is a problem on our agent maybe beacuse codecoverage.exe doesn't run well. Our next step is to run codecoverage on our machine not on ADOS.When I fix my error I will post my answer!

Answer (score 0):

> Can't see Code Coverage from my code with Azure DevOps Build

If you are using the **Azure Devops Srever (TFS 2019)**, there is a known issue on the Developer Community:

[Code coverage tab missing in Azure DevOps Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886206/reportgenerator-missing-code-coverage-tab-azure-devops-server-2019-0-1/56895832#56895832)

MS team reply: **A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.**

As workaround, you can try the method provided by jingzhu yan:

> you can add copy files and publish build results steps , then you
>   candownload coverage result file from Artifacts.

If you are using Azure Devops services, make sure you have enable **Code coverage enabled** on the VS test task:

[image]